# Child Element Moves Baseline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown widget that can be used inline, but when it opens it seems to lower the text baseline. I would have expected the children of the widget not to affect layout.

With some experimentation, I found that it matters whether or not there is text in the div, so there are two widgets in the following example.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('high')
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddf;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
}
.third {
display: block;  
}
.high {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Text</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>Text
```

It seems like the inner div is treated like text if there is not actual text. Is there a way to eliminate this behavior?

I can only change the divs and not what follows, so I'd be interested in a solution that allows me to make the parent div solely determine the baseline.

EDIT: Not making the child `display: inline-block` also seems to work. This seems to confirm that the contents are being treated as the "text" that matters. I'd still like to know why.

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your problem. I added only `float: left` to the `<div> 's`. Here's Fiddle `<http://jsfiddle.net/zlajaa1/ffebcww0/>`